# CUDA out of memory while using PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, generative-adversarial-network

Trying to reproduce the Super Resolution GAN from this repository — [Super Resolution](https://github.com/vishal1905/Super-Resolution/blob/master/SR_PT.ipynb) —  using Google Colab, but each time when I execute the final block of code the following error occurs:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-b9349075c05d> in <module>()
     16 
     17         gen_out = gen(torch.from_numpy(lr_images).to(cuda).float())
---> 18         _,f_label = disc(gen_out)
     19         _,r_label = disc(torch.from_numpy(hr_images).to(cuda).float())
     20         d1_loss = (disc_loss(f_label,torch.zeros_like(f_label,dtype=torch.float)))

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in batch_norm(input, running_mean, running_var, weight, bias, training, momentum, eps)
   2280 
   2281     return torch.batch_norm(
-> 2282         input, weight, bias, running_mean, running_var, training, momentum, eps, torch.backends.cudnn.enabled
   2283     )
   2284 

RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 256.00 MiB (GPU 0; 11.17 GiB total capacity; 10.29 GiB already allocated; 63.81 MiB free; 10.65 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

I've already tried to reduce the batch size but to no avail. How can this be addressed?

Comment: Have you tried using a very very small batchsize to see if it works?

Comment: Maybe some of your inputs got broadcasted because of wrong shapes from some operation like `*` or `+`

Comment: @FarhoodET Actually, I've risked changing the batch size from 64 to 1 and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @web_tracer memory profile your model and see whether you're using more than you need or not. Sometimes your model is too big to be for a colab environment. That's probably why batch size of 1 is working.

Answer (score 0):

Changing batch size from 64 to 1 eventually sorted out the issue. Kudos to @Farhood ET.